# How can I listen for monitors being added or removed?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

On Windows, how can I find out when monitors (physical display devices) are added/removed/detached/resolution changed/etc.?  I'd prefer not to poll EnumDisplayDevices().

Comment: I guess Monitor.Enter() and Monitor.Exit() don't help you.  ;)

Comment: This question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181064/enumdisplaydevices-vs-wmi-win32desktopmonitor-how-to-detect-active-monitors

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message in your main window.  It is sent to all top-level windows when a monitor is added or removed.  You'll get `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` when the resolution is changed.